# how to use search bar for name search and date search without padding / i.e automatically adding "/"

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

my app uses a uisearchbar and uitableview
I am able to search the names as well as the dates,but when i am searching for dates i am supposed to pad it "/" because it is stored it in that format in the database.
I have written a predicate to do this search.
This is what i have tried:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *txt=searchBar.text;
    BOOL canEdit=NO;

    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
    for (int i=0; i<[txt length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [txt characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            canEdit=NO;
        }
        else {
            canEdit=YES;
        }
    }

    if (canEdit) {
        searchBar.text=text;
        return canEdit;
    }

    else if(([txt length]==10 && range.location>11))
        return NO;
    2
    txt=[txt stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    txt=[txt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    txt=[txt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];

    NSMutableString *mutableText=[txt mutableCopy];

    for (NSUInteger i=2; i< mutableText.length && i<6;i+=3) {
        [mutableText insertString:@"/" atIndex:i];
    }

    txt=mutableText;
    if(txt.length > 10){
        txt=[txt stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, mutableText.length-10) withString:@""];

    }

    searchBar.text=txt;
    return NO;

}
```

how am i supposed to do search by automatically padding a "/" when i type for date in the search field.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",yourdate]` ?

Comment: I would suggest you use a picker for the date selection. Your loop logic is flawed so you are basically only testing the last character in txt (presumably you want to know if there is any non-alpha character in txt)